# Remove strings depending on partitial strings from a list with Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I know I have to work with a copy of my list here to remove items from it while iterating over it.

The example code here look for 3 sub-strings. This doesn't look like pythonic.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

with open('stringlist', 'r') as f:
    mylist = f.read().splitlines()

for s in mylist[:]:
    if 'Australia' in a:
        mylist.remove(s)
    if 'Canada' in a:
        mylist.remove(s)
    if 'USA' in a:
        mylist.remove(s)
```

How would this be done more elegant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something along the lines of:

```
unwanted = [
    'Australia',
    'Canada',
    'USA',
    ]

my_list = []
with open('stringlist') as source:
    for line in source:
        if any(word in line for word in unwanted):
            continue

        my_list.append(line)

print(my_list)
```

Code currently untested, but it should work...

### Addendum on `in-for-in`

You should probably read up on the following topics:

- [Generator expressions and list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html?highlight=comprehension#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions)
- [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- [Displays for lists, sets and dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=iterator#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries)

The `any(word in line for word in unwanted)` consists of three separate parts:

- `any(...)` – Returns `True` if any of the list elements is `True`
- `word in line` – A simple expression to test whether the `word` is found within the `line`
- `for word in unwanted` – An *internal* for loop, where we loop on the `unwanted` list placing each element into `word`

A longer version which does the same:

```
tmp_list = []
for word in unwanted:
    tmp_bool = word in line
    tmp_list.append(tmp_bool)

any(tmp_list)
```

When used with parenthesis, `( ... )`, it's called a generator expression, but this also often seen as a list comprehension where one use square brackets, `[ ... ]`.

```
odd_numbers = [number % 2 = 1 for number in range(10)]
```

Which would return the list of odd numbers below 10.

Comment: And again there is such a `in-for-in`-construct. I don't understand. :) Maybe you have a SA-link for that. Don't know how to _ask_ for that. And I think this question is answered somewhere. _What does in-for-in mean in Python?_

Comment: @buhtz, Have added a section on the `in-for-in` construct as you call it.